# File sharing for normal users in win7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

Using a domain environment
UAC is on

Is there a way to enable users to create file shares without needing elevated permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-enable network shares, and create a shared directory for each user in advance. I'd advise doing it the classic FTP way of their share being read-only, and create a directory within this directory called "Incoming" or something similar, with unversal write-access. This way they their shared files are protected but are still able to have others upload files to them when needed.

Comment: Would make it a bit of a pain when a user wants to share a project folder they would have to copy/move to the shared folder. We've also tried tweakui  as per this article but it does not work for win7 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2005/04/18/409105.aspx

Comment: In all things there's a balance. Security versus convenience, structure versus freedom. Yes it's more inconvenient to share select types of items via a pre-formed share structure, but it forces your users to stay somewhat organized and somewhat secure. This certainly isn't the only correct way though, and depending on your environment, the habits of your users, etc. I'm sure there's a middle ground which will satisfy the needs best.